# Inserting HTML template into tinymce 4 editor

Tags: javascript, html, templates, tinymce-4

I have a HTML templates on one  side. On the other hand, I have TinyMce Editor 4+ version. I have created
a HTMl page with buttons(with name "Use Template") for each of the template I will be using.

Basically, I want a user to click a corresponding template button and that should Insert the HTML
template into the tinyMCE editor.

Could anyone give me some ideas how should I start doing this ? I found most of the people are searching
online for how to insert HTML templates from the inbuilt option of "TinyMce" editor which I don't want.

Please provide your inputs.

**MORE CLARIFICATIONS**

I have a HTML page (say PAGE1) with several buttons named "USE TEMPLATE". So, basically, when a user clicks on "Use Template" button, he should be directed to next page(say PAGE2). Page 2 contains an email editor namely TinyMCE. The corresponding template for which the user has clicked the button must be inserted into the TinyMCE editor. I would like to know how should I proceed in this case?

Please don't confuse this with the INSERT --> INSERT TEMPLATE OPTION of the tinyMce. I know how to do this.

Comment: @Andrew Barber Did I make my question clear enough for others?

Answer (score 4):

If I am not wrong, make sure you tinymce has /tinymce/plugins/template:

```
tinymce.init({
    plugins: "xx,xxx,xxx,....,template",//<-- please add template as a plugin, also make sure you have [template] plugin in your tinymce/plugins
    templates: [ 
        {title: 'Some title 2', description: 'Some desc 2', url: 'development.html'} //remember put full path to url, and also the url can be a server side script file, such as: my_template.php?t=1
    ]
});
```

Reading: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/template/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't you think this answer is pertaining to the inbuilt feature of tinyMce which allows an option to "Insert Template" ? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: Well, it is a tinyMCE plugin. Even, it is built by tinyMCE officially, I would not call it inbuild feature. Some of the tinyMCE install package may not have the plugin in the first place. That is the reason why I said - make sure you tinymce has /tinymce/plugins/template .