# Create custom templates using ckeditor, tinymce or any online editor

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor, tinymce, editor

I am not sure if the title represents what exactly I need to do, But here is the details. I am building a website using PHP that allows people to create different templates, then they should select one of them and then fill the fields to fill the placeholders. For example consider the following image

[image]

The name of the recipient could be a placeholder so some part of the template can be

> Dear {recipient}
>
> {body}

and I prepare two fields for `recipient` and the `body` and it will be replaced by the value of the corresponding field. I can do this. What I can't do is how to let the user to align the placeholders in the paper. For example there is a placeholder for the `date` that must be at right of the page, or any other placeholder that can be place inside the paper (same as the following image). I would like to know if ckeditor or any other editor allows me to create such template?

The structure of the template must be kept in A4 or A5 print page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m having trouble understanding your question. If you're looking for templates in TinyMCE editor, I think you should try using template plugin for tinymce - [there](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-templates/) is one for wordpress. You can write your own plugin too, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647629/inserting-html-template-into-tinymce-4-editor) was question about it.